# Solving Inequality with positive numbers $a,b,c$.

Tags: inequality, solution-verification, alternative-proof

$a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}, 0\leq a,b,c \leq 1$, find max
$$\frac{a+b+c}{3}+\sqrt{a(1-a)+b(1-b)+c(1-c)}$$

My answer
let $t=\dfrac{a+b+c}{3}$, it will be
$$t+\sqrt{3t-(x^2+y^2+z^2)}\leq t+\sqrt{3t-3t^2}(\because \mathrm{CS})$$
Then $f(t)=t+\sqrt{3t-3t^2}$, and differentiate to find the extrema

Answer become $a=b=c=\dfrac{3}{4}$, and max is $\dfrac{3}{2}$.

Is there a better way of solving this?

Comment: It may be better if you share your work here.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a tour. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an edit): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance:https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959. To put it more bluntly,we are not going to do your homework for you.We’ll help only if you show what effort you made.

Comment: Added my answer

Comment: @Sterne : what is your question??

Comment: @sadman-ncc : I want to know better way to solve this question , especially way that don’t using deferential

Answer (score 1):

Avoiding derivative you can use CS again:

$$t+\sqrt{3t-3t^2}\leq \sqrt{2(t^2+3t-3t^2)} $$

with eqaulity iff $t^2 = 3t-3t^2$ i.e. $t=0$ or $t={3\over 4}$. Later choise give us $f(t) \leq {3\over 2}$